# Bot or script to take over a Hangout conversation

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Is it possible to implement a bot or program to take over a communication on my behalf is such way that my friend not notice it's not me who is responding?
Can I do this with Hangouts Bot or I need to implement an application with Hangouts API?

Answer (score 0):

Neither is possible. The Hangouts Chat API/Bots can only respond to messages addressed directly to the bot service account. It is not possible to intercept messages sent to other users.

Potentially, you could instead write a browser plugin to act on your behalf in a open chat windows.